# How to use command line to stop application from another pc

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I have 32 clients are running on MS Windows XP numbered as GON1NU01 to GON1NU32.
I want to stop application from command line to stop all or selected clients  "App_Stop_All".

What command should I use to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What have you done so far? Are there a list of specific things you tried - failed? Highlight your research effort in your question

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

[`taskkill`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true) can be used to kill processes on remote computers.

> Ends one or more tasks or processes. Processes can be killed by process ID or image name.
>
> Examples:
>
> - taskkill /s srvmain /f /im notepad.exe
> - taskkill /s srvmain /u maindom\hiropln /p p@ssW23 /fi "IMAGENAME eq note*" /im *

Combine that in a batch file with a [For loop](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true) that goes through a list of computers and you should be good to go.

Something like:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (computerlist.txt) do taskkill /s %%a /f /im notepad.exe
```